# Help! Where has Math.PI gone in F# CTP?

Tags: math, f#

I'm just trying to do simple scripting with F#, and Math.PI seems to have 'disappeared'. I've referenced FSharp.PowerPack.dll, but still can't find it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The constant pi is System.Math.PI, if you want to use, Math.PI just open System, in your fsharp file:

```
open System
Math.PI
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and can't test it now but have a look at Microsoft.FSharp.Math.

Answer (score -5):

You know, you could just do this:

```
let PI = 3.141592653589
```

Comment: Pending an answer I have, but it's a bit of a bummer to have to do that everywhere.